# solidity ERC20 transferFrom gives no error but does not execute

Tags: solidity, erc20

I have a Solidity code that aims to Exchange BUSD with myToken (both ERC20) which calls a BUSD.transferFrom() and a myToken.transfer(), but despite the core executes with no errors only myToken is transferred.
The account is approved and has enough balance.

Can you please point the error?

```
bytes4 private constant SELECTOR_TRANSFER = bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));
bytes4 private constant SELECTOR_TRANSFERFROM = bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')));


  function _myTokenTransfer(uint256 amount) private {
      _safeTransfer(myToken_addr, _msgSender(), amount);
  }
  
  function _busdTransfer(uint256 amount) private {
      _safeTransferFrom(busd_addr, _msgSender(), address(this), amount);
  }

  function _safeTransferFrom(address token, address from, address to, uint value) private {
      (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(SELECTOR_TRANSFERFROM, from , to, value));
      require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'myTokenPrivateSale: TRANSFERFROM_FAILED');
  }
  

  function _safeTransfer(address token, address to, uint value) private {
      (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(SELECTOR_TRANSFER, to, value));
      require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'myTokenPrivateSale: TRANSFER_FAILED');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Can you link a transaction that executes the `_busdTransfer` (without errors and without token transferred)?

Comment: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xfb8e3e0d2895a87edb3ffc05e8f43dd6a8e822bc1467d8246032a04252eca008

Comment: https://github.com/vinimia/smart-contracts/blob/main/VINIPrivateSale.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `busd_addr` is unset (i.e. `0x0`).

When the `_safeTransferFrom()` function gets executed, it sends an internal transaction to the `0x0` address. The transaction doesn't revert (there's no contract that would throw an exception on the `0x0` address) and doesn't return any data (again, no contract that would return any data).

```
(bool success, bytes memory data)
// `success` is true because it didn't revert
// `data` is 0x00, the default value
```

The validation then passes as if it were sucessful.

```
require(success && (data.length == 0 || ...));
// `success` is true
// `data.length` is 0, so the rest of the OR condition is ignored
```

---

I see that you [executed](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x10ce9236e6f9ae9c6fecebb98457d08435f23e14b0100a514b195fc53f34825e) the `setBUSD()` function. But this function doesn't set the `busd_addr` value, that is used in the `_safeTransferFrom()` function. *(It only sets the `busd` and `busd_set`.)*

There's currently no way to set the `busd_addr` value in your code. So you'll need to make the proper changes in your code - set `busd_addr` value in the `setBUSD()` function, and then redeploy your contract.